# Jquery select on view level jquery datepicker template without declaring datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented datepicker with jquery editortemplates.However on certain View pages i need to add onselect event for datepicker . The datepicker code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.dateofbirth').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
</script>
```

has been put  on _layout.cshtml . Now i cant trigger the necesary event on the child pages widout declaring the datepicker element again. Is there any way tht i can just fire the datepicker onselect method and perform something on my own on child pages and the datepicker configuration and intialisation remains on the _layout.cshtml ?

something like this

View 1:

```
$('#dob').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { /*Calculate Age*/ }});
```

View 2:

```
$('#addmonths').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { /*Calculate New maturity Date*/ }});
```

I just dont want to redeclair the  Datepicker element for #element again on child page. Let the initialisation being taken care by editor template but on child pages i just want to call **onSelect** method for each of those as needed without redeclaration .

Is there anyway i can just call the methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Try simply setting only one option by using the "option"-method.

```
$('#dob').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function(dateText, inst) { /*Calculate Age*/ });
```

By using the default way for init - your parameter-object will be extendet with the defaults (implemented in datepicker) and the passed to the init-method.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-option

You can even set system-wide defaults for datepicker.
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/setDefaults

Comment: you mean to say it wouldn't effect the default settings right ? It would actually extend the default settings with the onSelect event functions without reinitializing the datepicker ?

Comment: sorry? you can change the defaults if you use `setDefaults`.     If you simply initialize your input with an option-array or add one option, you will extend the defaults only for the selected input. But the defaults will stay the same for other inputs with a datepicker.

Comment: Its not resolved yet . The setDefaults works fine . But when in child page i try to do this $('#Customer_DateOfBirth').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function (dateText, inst) {
    alert(dateText);
});
It simply does nothing . I mean the method isnt fired :(

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer here . If i set defaults to the datepicker then all default settings would be applied . However if i have to put onSelect we have to again

```
$('#dob').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { /*Calculate Age*/ }});
```

it doesnt recreate the datepicker actually . What it does is . If any **default settings** is provided to the datepicker . those datepicker settings are applied and the select Event is attached to the existing datepicker once it finds the datepicker is already initialized . So on the contrary the datepicker isnt recreated rather it just attaches the **onSelect Event** to it